# Spring Config with JUnit temporary folder

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit4, spring-test

Hi I am looking for a way to use the JUnit's TemporaryFolder inside the Spring config file. But I am getting the following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: the temporary folder has not yet been created
   at org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder.getRoot(TemporaryFolder.java:127)
   at org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder.newFolder(TemporaryFolder.java:92)
   at org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder.newFolder(TemporaryFolder.java:84)
```

This is my setup

```
@Configuration
public static class TestConfig {
    @ClassRule
    private final static TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder ();   

    @Bean
    public TestBean testBean(){
       return new TestBean(tempFolder.newFolder();
    }

}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
public SomeTesT{


}
```

I even tried to initialize the TemporaryFolder in the static block and that did not work either.

Comment: can you try moving @ClassRule part to `SomeTest`

Comment: I need the temporary folder in the TestConfig

Comment: Try changing private to public since `@ClassRule` can only understand public static fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `TemporaryFolder` like that in JUnit after 4.10. Prior to version 4.10, `TemporaryFolder` could have been used without `@Rule` annotations. In version 4.10 a change has been made and only two methods enforce that. In version 4.11 all the methods in `TemporaryFolder` enforce this rule.

What you have in your code is exactly that: usage of TemporaryFolder without `@Rule`s. The fact that you add `@ClassRule` in the `@Configuration` class doesn't have anything to do with JUnit and JUnit will not recognize your annotation, because the code is not in a JUnit test class. A change in version 4.11, meaning [this one](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/issues/342), made all the methods in `TemporaryFolder` to enforce the use of `@Rule` annotations.

You have two options:

1. Stick with JUnit 4.10 and use your code as is
2. Use Junit 4.11 but your code needs to change. Here's one approach (moving the `@Configuration` class inside `SomeTest`):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration()
public class SomeTest {
    @ClassRule
    public final static TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Autowired
    private TestBean testBean;

    @Configuration
    static class Config {
        @Bean
        public TestBean testBean() {
            try {
                return new TestBean(tempFolder.newFolder());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for poiting this out, but isn't there a better solution? Should there be a solution by spring itself?

Comment: @Zarathustra I tried with success to put the `@ClassRule` field & `@Configuration` static class in a super abstract class. At least I could factorize this peace of code.